# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I’ve added a fragment to my main layout. But when i lunch it the app crash and the error log show this: `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment`. I think i have do all things right but I don't where is the error :/.

**My Main Layout :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/dark_grey"
tools:context="com.example.user.unchained.HomesActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/homeList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector" />

<fragment
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.example.user.unchained.FooterHome"
    android:id="@+id/homeFooter"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    tools:layout="@layout/footer_home" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**My Fragment :**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000"
android:id="@+id/homeFooter"
tools:context="com.example.user.unchained.FooterHome">


<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:text="What's New ?"
android:textSize="16dip"
android:layout_marginTop="12dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/status"
android:id="@+id/watsN"
android:textColor="@color/connexion_button"
android:layout_gravity="left|top" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text=" | "
    android:textSize="25dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="145dip"
    android:textColor="@color/connexion_button"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Check In"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="165dip"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/checkin"
    android:id="@+id/checkIn"
    android:textColor="@color/connexion_button"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text=" | "
    android:textSize="25dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="265dip"
    android:textColor="@color/connexion_button"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text=" Picture"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="290dip"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/camera"
    android:id="@+id/postPic"
    android:textColor="@color/connexion_button"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top" />

   </FrameLayout>
```

**The Fragment Class :**

```
public class FooterHome extends Fragment {

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static FooterHome newInstance() {
    FooterHome fragment = new FooterHome();

    return fragment;
}
public FooterHome() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_home, container, false);
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

}
```

Comment: post `com.example.user.unchained.FooterHome`

Comment: i've update the question body :

Comment: Change this "com.example.user.unchained.FooterHome" to com.example.user.unchained.FooterFragment

Comment: is footerHome sorry i've past the wrong fragment but it is sur is footerHome

Comment: Try changing the id for fragment "@+id/homeFooter", since the same name has been assigned to Framelayout, so a Conflict of Id's may occur a problem to access your fragment.. @KANDROIDOS

Comment: @Brendon still having the problem

Comment: Ok now change your fragment class extended to Fragment to "FragmentActivity" and check.. @KANDROIDOS

Comment: sorry to dispoint you but it"s not working

Comment: OK then post your logcat so that i can figure out clearly what is the problem

Comment: i've fixed now, but it's working just one time when i change the fragment in the navigation drawer and i try for the second time to get the this fragment it's show me this error `Binary XML file line #16: Duplicate id 0x7f070083, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.example.user.unchained.FooterHome`